# ArcGIS Online - My Hosted Services

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, generate-tiles

I am looking for a solution to a problem I have using ArcGIS Online.  I am currently creating 5 Tiled Map Packages which I tile on my ArcGIS for Desktop then Publish to my ArcGIS Online Account to save using any credits.  Once the Tiled Map Package is Published I can then email my colleague the URL (REST) which he then feeds into his ArcGIS Server.

He has asked me if I can group the Services together into one URL so that he can display the 5 Published Services as a Group instead of individual Layers.

Is this possible?

Comment: Provide more info on what your colleague intends to do.  What client is he wanting to serve them up in? Is s/he developing an application? I think you have done the right thing and s/he might need to be the one that needs to do something different.